# How to get Difference from two dates in form of days hours minutes and seconds

Tags: android, timer

I have two dates one is Future date and other is Current date.
I want to get the difference between these two dates i am using following code but output is not what i want kindly help me through this. i am new to android programming.

```
public void getDateDifference(String FutureDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try {

        Date currentDate = dateFormat.parse(FutureDate);
        System.out.println(currentDate);

        Date oldDate = new Date();

        long diff = currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime();
        long seconds = diff / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;
        long hours = minutes / 60;
        long days = hours / 24;

        counterDaysTV.setText(days + "");
        counterMinsTV.setText(minutes + "");
        counterHoursTV.setText(hours + "");
        counterSecTV.setText(seconds + "");


    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

i am using this method to find the difference but it shows like 71 days that is right but next it shows 1716 hours 102987 minutes and 6179267 seconds I want it to show like a countdown kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always calculate with the whole time difference.

You first have to calculate the days, then with the remainder the hours. Then with this remainder the minutes and so on.

```
public void getDateDifference(String FutureDate) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try {
        Date currentDate = dateFormat.parse(FutureDate);
        System.out.println(currentDate);

        Date oldDate = new Date();

        long diff = currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime();

        long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
        diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);

        long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
        diff -= minutes * (60 * 1000);

        long seconds = diff / 1000;

        counterDaysTV.setText(days + "");
        counterMinsTV.setText(minutes + "");
        counterHoursTV.setText(hours + "");
        counterSecTV.setText(seconds + "");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below code may works,,just give a try...note that it is not efficient method i think...

```
        long days = diff / (24*60*60*1000);
        long hours=(diff/(60*60*1000))-(days*24);
        long minutes=(diff/(60*1000))-(days*24*60)-(hours*60);
        long seconds=(diff/(1000))-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have some modification to the answer of davidtrautmann, thanx to davidtrautmann. User can find better way for getting difference between current time and past date in days,hours,minuts and seconds. Users can also modify as per their requirement.

```
public String getDifferentBetweenTwoDates(String pastDate ){//your input date format should be same as your dateformater

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date inputDate = null;
    try {
        inputDate = format.parse(pastDate); // format.parse("2016-04-04 20:10:10");

    }catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar pastCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(inputDate!=null){
        pastCalendar.setTime(inputDate);
    }
    long pastDateTimeInMilli = pastCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

    Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long currentDateTimeInMilli = currentCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

    String strDifference="";
    long different = currentDateTimeInMilli - pastDateTimeInMilli;

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    int elapsedDays = (int)(different / daysInMilli);
    different = different % daysInMilli;

    if(elapsedDays>0){
        strDifference = ""+elapsedDays;
        return strDifference+" days ago";
    }

    int elapsedHours = (int)(different / hoursInMilli);
    different = different % hoursInMilli;
    if(elapsedHours>0){
        strDifference = ""+elapsedHours;
        return strDifference+" hours ago";
    }

    int elapsedMinutes = (int)(different / minutesInMilli);
    different = different % minutesInMilli;
    if(elapsedMinutes>0){
        strDifference = ""+elapsedMinutes;
        return strDifference+" minuts ago";
    }

    int elapsedSeconds = (int)(different / secondsInMilli);
    if(elapsedSeconds>0){
        strDifference = ""+elapsedSeconds;
        return strDifference +"  seconds ago";
    }else{
        return "just now";
    }

}
```